# How to separate string to number in single word with PHP?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I have the word AK747, I use regex to detect if a string (at least 2 chars ex: AK) is followed by a number (at least to digits ex: 747).
EDIT : (sorry that I wasn't clear on this guys)
I need to do this above because :

In some case I need to split to match search against AK-747. When I search for string 'AK-747' with keyword 'AK747' it won't find a match unless I use levenshtein in database, so I prefer splitting AK747 to AK and 747.

My code:

```
$strNumMatch = preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]{2,}[0-9]{2,}$/', 
$value, $match);

if(isset($match[0]))
    echo $match[0];
```

How do I split to array ['AK', '747'] for example with preg_split() or any other way?

Comment: so it should split on both cases `AK747` and `AK-747`?

Comment: @jh1711 cheers! Thanks. The group capture was the key. I just accepted an answer similar to your comment, I upvoted your comment. Your name jh1711 is like the example may be that's you knew it so easily.

Comment: @mickmackusa, done! I use comments to post quick thoughts that might be a solution, but don't have proper explanation or references to count as a good answer (imo). Everybody is free to use those thoughts, and I did not see any harm. But I will read guidelines again, and rethink my strategy.

Comment: @mickmackusa thanks for the tip, I'll use it from now on.

Comment: @jh1711 while rethinking your strategy, please consider some of my points @ https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/hey-you-yeah-you-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$input = 'AK-747';

if (preg_match('/^([a-z]{2,})-?([0-9]{2,})$/i', $input, $result)) {
    unset($result[0]);
}

print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => AK
    [2] => 747
)
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear on that part of my question. I only need AK747 to split to AK and 747, I did not needed for AK-747. But you got I OK with the optional - and the group capture. I already accepted a similar answer before I read and test yours. But you deserve it.

Comment: I accepted this answer instead for the sake of this community. It is more simple, clear, direct and even take my misleading "-" into account. So I think other users might find this easier and more appropriate, that's why I switched to that answer.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
preg_match('/[0-9]{2,}/', $value, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
$position = $matches[0][1];
$letters = substr($value, 0, $position);
$numbers = substr($value, $position);
```

This way you get the position of the first number and split there.

**EDIT**:
Starting from your original approach this could look somewhat like this:

```
$strNumMatch = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{2,})([0-9]{2,})$/', $value, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
if($strNumMatch){
    $position = $matches[2][1];
    $letters = substr($value, 0, $position);
    $numbers = substr($value, $position);
    $alternative = $letters.'-'.$numbers;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks man! That's exactly what I wanted. The key was to use the group capture with parenthesis. Only instead of searching strings with position, I use $strNumMatch = preg_match('/^([a-zA-Z]{2,})([0-9]{2,})$/', $value, $match); and I leave the PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE option. I can now access values the array as Array ([0] => AK747 [1] => AK [2] => 747).

Comment: If you have to use `substr()` to extract substrings AFTER calling a `preg_` function, then you've probably called the wrong function and/or used an inadequate pattern.  This is not a direct/professional solution.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_split()` is a very sensible and direct call since you desire an indexed array containing the two substrings.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d53377e2b8fc731ad500d4fb409b9146e7646c25))

```
$input = 'AK-747';
var_export(preg_split('/[a-z]{2,}\K-?/i',$input));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'AK',
  1 => '747',
)
```

The `\K` means "restart the fullstring match".  Effectively, everything to the left of `\K` is retained as the first element in the result array and everything to right (the optional hyphen) is omitted because it is considered the delimiter.  [Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WbOqVW/1)

---

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ed653f64e94a47790038cb1ba453ce22616f45c))

I process a small battery of inputs to show what can be done and explain after the snippet.

```
$inputs=['AK747','AK-747','AK-','AK'];  // variations as I understand them
foreach($inputs as $input){
    echo "$input returns: ";
    var_export(preg_split('/[a-z]{2,}\K-?/i',$input,2,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
AK747 returns: array (
  0 => 'AK',
  1 => '747',
)
AK-747 returns: array (
  0 => 'AK',
  1 => '747',
)
AK- returns: array (
  0 => 'AK',
)
AK returns: array (
  0 => 'AK',
)
```

[preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) takes a pattern that receives a pattern that will match a variable substring and use it as a delimiter.  If `-` were present in every input string then `explode('-',$input)` would be most appropriate.  However, `-` is optional in this task, so the pattern must allow `-` to be optional (this is what the `?` quantifier does in all of the patterns on this page).

Now, you couldn't just use a pattern like `/-?/`, [that would split the string on every character](https://regex101.com/r/WbOqVW/2).  To overcome this, you need to tell the regex engine the exact expected location for the optional `-`.  You do this by referencing `[a-z]{2,}` before the `-?` (single intended delimiter).

The pattern `/[a-z]{2,}-?/i` does a fair job of finding the correct location for the optional hyphen, but now the trouble is, the leading letters in the string are included as [part of the delimiting substring](https://regex101.com/r/WbOqVW/3).

Sometimes, "lookarounds" can be used in regex patterns to match but not consume substrings.  A "positive lookbehind" is used to match a preceding substring, however ["variable length lookbehinds" are not permitted in php (and most other regex flavors)](https://regex101.com/r/WbOqVW/4).  This is what the invalid pattern would look like: `/(?<=[a-z]{2,})-?/i`.

The way around this technicality is to "restart the fullstring match" using the [\K](https://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html) token (aka [a lookbehind alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2943403)) just before the optional hyphen.  To correctly target only the intended delimiter, the leading letters must be "matched/consumed" then "discarded" -- that's what `\K` does.

As for the inclusion of the 3rd and 4th parameter of `preg_split()`...

- I've set the 3rd parameter to `2`.  This is just like the `limit` parameter that `explode()` has.  It instructs the function to not make more than 2 output elements.  For this case, I could have used `NULL` or `-1` to mean "unlimited", but I could NOT leave the parameter empty -- it must be assigned to allow for the declaration of the 4th parameter.
- I've set the 4th parameter to `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` which instructs the function to not generate empty output elements.

Ta-Da!

---

---

p.s. a `preg_match_all()` [solution](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/11d2d8e62f0449a3cf8d40e46e486fe834fdfca9) is as easy as using a pipe and two anchors:

```
$inputs=['AK747','AK-747','AK-','AK'];  // variations as I understand them
foreach($inputs as $input){
    echo "$input returns: ";
    var_export(preg_match_all('/^[a-z]{2,}|\d{2,}$/i',$input,$out)?$out[0]:[]);
    echo "\n";
}
// same outputs as above
```

Comment: Thanks. I just tested it so basically it separate letters from any other non-letter characters, not just digits. I understand `preg_split()` now.

Comment: Also I noticed it will split any pure text from the empty string after the last letter. Like 'AK' will output: `array ( 0 => 'AK', 1 => '', )` . That has the effect of splitting any text. That may be useful, but in some case you may want a split only if the non-letter char is not the last empty string.

Comment: @KeitelJovin I've added a new expanded snippet/demo and a whole bunch of explanation to help you understand how it works.  Ask me more questions if anything is unclear to you.

Comment: Many thanks! Specially for the `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag, and the limit. That prepares my mind for much more flexible approach for future iterations.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the `-` optional with `?`.

```
/([A-Za-z]{2,}-?[0-9]{2,})/
```

https://regex101.com/r/tIgM4F/1